# How to associate *.md files with my editor?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, nemo, markdown

I want to open markdown files by double clicking on them in Sublime Text.
I tried every possible way, but I could not achieve it.

I created the `mimeapps.list` file with this content:

```
[Default Applications]
text/markdown=sublime_text.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/markdown=sublime_text.desktop
```

And put this file in the directory `~/.config/`
This did not change anything

I also added this `text/markdown=sublime_text.desktop` line in the file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`

I tried to put the `mimeapps.list` these paths:
`~/.local/share/applications`
`/usr/share/applications`

I also checked `/usr/share/mime/text` and found a file `markdown.xml` that describe the markdown file format for the system

Some checks show that the system sees the markdown files correctly:

```
~/Desktop$ mimetype test.md 
test.md: text/markdown    

~$ xdg-mime query default text/markdown
sublime_text.desktop  

~/Desktop$ mimeopen test.md 
Opening "test.md" with Sublime Text  (text/markdown)
```

But the `.md` files are still open in default application (*xed* in my case)

I know there is the easiest way to associate markdown files. In the context menu in the file manager, select the "Set as default"
[image]

Under the hood, it works not for `text/markdown` files but for `text/plain`. And I only need markdown files

**Linux Mint 19**
**Cinnamon 3.8.8**
**nemo 3.8.5**

Answer (score 4):

Sorry my fault.
I tested the empty `test.md`, but when I added some markdown markup inside the file it all worked.

`~/.config/mimeapps.list` - this file works like a charm